# Draw circle on JPanel after mouse click

Tags: java, swing

I want to draw circle only after mouse gets click. As paintComponent method called itself, so first circle draw without click.

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int x, y;

public DrawPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    repaint();
}

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You never call `super.paintComponent();`
2. You only have one `x` and `y`
3. Note how when you resize the frame, some circles will disappear and it overall behaves in a strange way.
4. I would store all the `Point`s where the user has clicked in an `ArrayList` and then loop through that list inside the `paintComponent` method. This way you can call `super.paintComponent();` without the circles disappearing.

**Changed, working code:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<Point> points;

    public DrawPanel() {
        points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                points.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        for (Point point : points) {
            g2.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new DrawPanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted. thanks for nice explanation

Comment: After maximizing/minimizing, a circle doesn't maintain their relative position w.r.t frame. eg: I clicked in the center of a frame, when frame size=400x400, but after maximizing, it position changes to the corner of the frame?

Comment: @Ranjeet That's how it's supposed to be, since the x and y coordinates of each circle never change. So do you want relative coordinates where the gap from each direction has the same 'ratio' at every frame size?

Answer (score 5):

You should place your circle inside its own class. That class will hold information on its location, radius, and its color. You can abstract your shape and have a list of shapes to draw on the panel. This will make it easy to implement a triangle, square, hexagon, etc. later.

You can add more methods and attributes to your shape objects later and only have to change their internal implementation of THEIR OWN `paintComponent(g)` method. This makes the `DrawPanel` depend on how each `Shape` does its own drawing.

[image: App screenshot]

---

#### App.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Circle Click Application");
                DrawPanel p = new DrawPanel(10f);

                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));;

                f.setContentPane(p);
                f.pack();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### DrawPanel.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6817035652787391530L;

    private List<Shape> shapes;
    protected float radius;

    private float sat = 0.7f;
    private float bri = 0.8f;

    public DrawPanel(float radius) {
        this.shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        this.radius = radius;

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
            shape.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        shapes.add(new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY(), radius, ColorUtils.randHue(sat, bri)));

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

#### Shape.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public interface Shape {
    Point getOrigin();
    void setOrigin(Point origin);

    Color getColor();
    void setColor(Color color);

    void paintComponent(Graphics g);
}
```

#### Circle.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Circle implements Shape {
    private Point origin;
    private float radius;
    private Color color;

    public Circle() {
        this(0, 0, 0.5f, Color.BLACK);
    }

    public Circle(int x, int y, float radius, Color color) {
        this(new Point(x, y), radius, color);
    }

    public Circle(Point origin, float radius, Color color) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public Point getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOrigin(Point origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public float getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(float radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int diameter = (int) (this.radius * 2);
        int x = (int) (origin.x - this.radius);
        int y = (int) (origin.y - this.radius);

        g.setColor(this.color);
        g.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }
}
```

#### ColorUtils.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class ColorUtils {
    private static final Random RAND;

    static {
        RAND = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static Color randHue(float saturation, float brightness) {
        return Color.getHSBColor(RAND.nextFloat(), saturation, brightness);
    }
}
```

---

## Extension

You can easily add a class such as a `Triangle` just by implementing the `Shape` interface.

#### DrawPanel#mouseClicked

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean isEven = time % 2 == 0;

    if (isEven) {
        shapes.add(new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY(), radius, ColorUtils.randHue(sat, bri)));
    } else {
        shapes.add(new Triangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), radius * 2, ColorUtils.randHue(sat, bri)));
    }

    repaint();
}
```

#### Triangle.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Triangle implements Shape {
    private Point origin;
    private float side;
    private Color color;

    private Polygon poly;

    public Triangle(int x, int y, float side, Color color) {
        this(new Point(x, y), side, color);
    }

    public Triangle(Point origin, float side, Color color) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.side = side;
        this.color = color;

        recalculate();
    }

    protected void recalculate() {
        this.poly = createPolygon((float) origin.getX(), (float) origin.getY(), side, false);
    }

    protected Polygon createPolygon(float x, float y, float side, boolean invert) {
        float xOff = side / 2f;
        float yOff = (float) (xOff * Math.sqrt(3));

        float r1 = 1f / 3f;
        float r2 = 2f / 3f;

        if (invert) {
            yOff *= -1;
        }

        return createPolygon(new Point2D.Float[] {
            new Point2D.Float(x,        y - (yOff * r2)), // Top
            new Point2D.Float(x - xOff, y + (yOff * r1)), // Left
            new Point2D.Float(x + xOff, y + (yOff * r1))  // Right
        });
    }

    protected Polygon createPolygon(Point2D.Float[] points) {
        int nPoints = points.length + 1;
        int xCoords[] = new int[nPoints];
        int yCoords[] = new int[nPoints];

        for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {
            xCoords[i] = (int) points[i % points.length].x;
            yCoords[i] = (int) points[i % points.length].y;
        }

        return new Polygon(xCoords, yCoords, nPoints);
    }

    @Override
    public Point getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOrigin(Point origin) {
        this.origin = origin;

        recalculate();
    }

    public float getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(float side) {
        this.side = side;

        recalculate();
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(this.color);
        g.fillPolygon(poly);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation with multiple classes and different shapes. How did you store shape object into the List? I didn't find "shape.add(shape)" .

Comment: @Ranjeet It's located in the `DrawPanel#mouseClicked` method: `shapes.add(new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY(), radius, ColorUtils.randHue(sat, bri)));`

Answer (score 4):

You should have some initial state, so you know not to draw when it is set.

This can be done with an easy boolean variable, that you set to true when the user has pressed on the screen.

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int x, y;
boolean mustDraw = false;

public DrawPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if(!mustDraw) return;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    mustDraw = true;
    repaint();
}

}
```