# Can't draw oval on JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw ovals on JPanel when mouse clicked. My code doesn't call paintComponent, so nothing happens on JPanel. Which part I'm missing?

```
 public class Main extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
        JPanel thePanel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
             protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
               {
                  super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                for (Circle c : circles){
                      g.fillOval(c.x, c.y, c.diameter, c.diameter);
                      System.out.println(c.x + "a");
                }

               }
        };
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        int x,y;
        ArrayList<Circle >circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new Main();
                }
            });
        }
    public Main(){

        frame.setSize(512,512);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addMouseListener(this);
        frame.add(thePanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }   

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getX());
            Circle c = new Circle();
            c.x=e.getX();
            c.y=e.getY();
            c.diameter=10;
            circles.add(c);
            repaint();
    }
```

circle class

```
class Circle
    {
      public int x, y, diameter;
    }
```

I didn't use getters and setters but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Your panel is not getting repainted. Try `thePanel.repaint()` instead of `repaint()`.

Comment: I think this question is a **duplicate** of the same problem asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299786/draw-circle-on-jpanel-after-mouse-click/35300018

Comment: `public class Main extends JFrame..` 1) `Main` is an extremely undescriptive (& therefore unhelpful) name. Make it meaningful. Something like `OvalGUI` would be more descriptive. 2) There is no need to extend `JFrame` since: A) The GUI creates one. B) No methods of the `JFrame` class are being overridden.

Comment: @onlyhuman It's not a duplicate of that. The code in that other question has a bunch of different problems, but not the same problem as this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your `repaint()` to `thePanel.repaint()`, you should be able to see the circles being added.

They will appear to be a little off-position, because you are getting frame-coordinates from your frame's mouse listener, but trying to paint in panel-coordinates.

Edit:
As camickr pointed out in his comment, you actually have two `JFrame`s: the one instantiated by `new JFrame()`, and the one instantiated by `new Main()`. This is the reason your `repaint` was not having the desired effect: the one you were calling `repaint` on was not the one you were looking at. camickr suggests that you do not inherit your `Main` from `JFrame`, which is good advice.

Comment: Well, I'm not cool with java GUI, it worked khelwood, thanks.

Comment: (1-) `Calling repaint() on your frame does not necessarily trigger a paint for your panel` - A repaint() on a frame will repaint all the child components of the frame.

Comment: @camickr You're quite right. I should have looked closer before answering.

Comment: @NerdicSapo, The problem is that the class extends JFrame AND creates another JFrame and you are repainting the wrong frame. Don't extend JFrame, it is confusing and unnecessary! Note however, that it is more efficient to only repaint the panel instead of the entire firame. I suggest you look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for a working example that will show you how to better structure your code to prevent this problem

Answer (score 0):

Draw oval and dragged width and height  by mouse

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.Point;

public class DrawOval extends Applet implementsMouseListener,MouseMotionListener {

    private int xstart,xend,ystart,yend;
    private boolean flag=false;
    private int width,heigth;
    private Point clickPoint;
    private Point dragPoint;
    private int x,y;

    public void init() {
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics p) {
        if (flag) {
            p.drawOval(x, y, width, heigth);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        clickPoint = me.getPoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        dragPoint = me.getPoint();
        x = Math.min(clickPoint.x, dragPoint.x);
        y = Math.min(clickPoint.y, dragPoint.y);
        width = Math.max(clickPoint.x, dragPoint.x) - x;
        heigth = Math.max(clickPoint.y, dragPoint.y) - y;

        flag = true;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {

    }
}
```