# Unable to access parent class variable value in child class

Tags: java

I am running into an issue with trying to access a variable (R)'s value from Parent Class(DrawingPanel()) in Child Class(Balloon()).

I have set the public integer R equal to 0 in DrawingPanel()'s class constructor. Like this:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, 
MouseMotionListener, KeyListener 
{
...
public int R;
// Constructor:
public DrawingPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addKeyListener(this);
    ...
    R = 0;
}
```

The mouse click to the Balloon object in JPanel is detected via the mousePressed() method(Part of DrawingPanel() class). See below:

```
// Called when the mouse is clicked on the drawing panel.
// If inside a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the offsets
// of the click from the center.
// If on the border of a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the
// distance of the click from the center.
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    ...
    R = 1;
    System.out.print(R);
    ...
}
```

In the Child Class, Balloon(), the DrawingPanel() Parent Class is inherited and the value for R is printed to console. Like this:

```
     /**
     * Represents a balloon in the BalloonDraw program.
     * Author: Willy Bolly
     * Ver 1.0 Created 12/31/17
     */

    import java.awt.Canvas;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Balloon extends DrawingPanel
    {
       int xCenter, yCenter, radius, rotate = RotateState();
       Color color;

      /**
       * Constructs a balloon with the center at (0, 0),
       * radius 50, and blue color
       */
      public Balloon()
      {  
        xCenter = 0;
        yCenter = 0;
        radius = 50;
        color = Color.BLUE;
      }

      /**
       * Constructs a balloon with a given center, radius and color
       * @param x x-coordinate of the center
       * @param y y-coordinate of the center
       * @param r radius of the balloon
       * @param c color of the balloon
       */
      public Balloon(int x, int y, int r, Color c)
      {   
        xCenter = x;
        yCenter = y;
        radius = r;
        color = c;

      }


      /**
       * Returns the x-coordinate of the center.
       */
      public int getX()
      {
        System.out.println(rotate);   
        return xCenter;
      }

      /**
       * Returns the y-coordinate of the center.
       */
      public int getY()
      {
        return yCenter;
      }

      /**
       * Returns the radius of this balloon.
       */
      public int getRadius()
      {
        return radius;
      }

      /**
       * Returns the color of this balloon.
       */
      public Color getColor()
      {
        return color;
      }

      /**
       * Returns the distance from a given point to the
       * center of this balloon.
       * @param x, y coordinates of the point
       */
      public double distance(int x, int y)
      {
        double dx = x - xCenter;
        double dy = y - yCenter;
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
      }

      /**
       * Moves the center of this balloon to (x, y)
       * @param x x-coordinate of the new center
       * @param y y-coordinate of the new center
       */
      public void move(int x, int y)
      {
        xCenter = x;
        yCenter = y;
      }

      /**
       * Sets the radius of this balloon to r
       * @param r new radius
       */
      public void setRadius(int r)
      {
        radius = r;
      }

      /**
       * Returns true if a given point is strictly inside this balloon;
       * otherwise returns false
       * @param x, y coordinates of the point
       */
      public boolean isInside(int x, int y)
      {
        return distance(x, y) < 0.9 * radius;
      }

      /**
       * Returns true if a given point is on the border of this balloon;
       * otherwise returns false
       * @param x, y coordinates of the point
       */
      public boolean isOnBorder(int x, int y)
      {   
        double d = distance(x, y);
        return d >= 0.9 * radius && d <= 1.1 * radius;
      }

      //Returns R value from DrawingPanel() class
        public int RotateState()
      {
        return R;
      }

      /**
   * Draws a solid circle if makeItFilled is true and
   * outline only if makeItFilled is false
   * @param g graphics context
   * @param makeItFilled draws a solid circle if true
   */
  public void draw(Graphics g, boolean makeItFilled)
  {


  }
 }
```

The Balloon() class for some reason only picks up and outputs the value of R that is declared in the constructor of the DrawingPanel() class. However, it fails to return the updated value for variable R after it changes when the mousePressed() method initiates.

Can someone please identify why this issue may be happening? Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: Where does your balloon class print `R` to the console?  The only place I see a print statement is in `getX()`, which isn't called anywhere in your code.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "it fails to return the updated value for variable R"?  I don't see any method that returns the value of `R`.  In fact, `R` doesn't seem to be used for anything at all in `Balloon`.

Comment: @azurefrog now the Balloon does have a main method that accesses the value of R returned by the RotateState method in Balloon class.

Comment: Again, the main you've posted won't compile.  `rotate` is an instance variable won't be accessible from a static context.  Please don't post non-working approximations of your actual code.  Post the real code, or ideally a [mcve].  Also, even if you were accessing `rotate` properly, you haven't shown the code where you invoke `RotateState()` to update it.  Currently it's only set during object initialization, where it's declared.

Comment: @azurefrog I sincerely apologize for your confusion. In my code, I basically had a method called draw, which acted as a parent method for sub classes of the Balloon class in place of the main method. Speaking of the RotateState() method, it is updated as the R variable is updated when the mousePressed() method is activated and both the RotateState() and mousePressed() methods are shown above. I am editing the post to include the draw method and the original location where I placed the System.out.println(rotate) statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Balloon` class you should override the `mouseClicked` method and implement its class specific logic.

So, add this to the `Balloon` class:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    super.mousePressed(e);
    // Do stuff with R
    getX();
}
```

Comment: `Balloon` already inherits the `mousePressed()` implementation from `DrawingPanel`.  Why would it need to override it?

Comment: It makes more sense when code that uses `R` in `Balloon` is added. You override it so you can add logic that is needed in the `Balloon` class. I edited my answer

Comment: @Tahfimul then why did you unmark this as an answer and selected the one answer that referenced my answer? :/ Good luck with your programming

Comment: @TadijaBagarić Apologies. I thought I could mark both answers. I noticed that I could only mark one answer. Yes your answer deserves it because it is more adequate and original.

Comment: @TadijaBagarić I have noticed now that for some reason, overriding is not working. Previously, I thought it was working because I had set the R variable equal to 1 in the constructor of DrawingPanel() class, which is why the console was printing 1 when I put the System.out.println(R) statement in  the Balloon() class. Would you suggest any other solution?

Comment: @Tahfimul Hmm looks like you edited your code. It is getting much harder to see what is going on. Here is a link to Java Doc about MouseListeners with an example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html
There you can find the source code of the example. Hope it helps. Also here is a similar SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299786/draw-circle-on-jpanel-after-mouse-click/35300018

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible that because of the inheritance, the instances of `Baloon` and `DrawingPanel` are seen as seperate and therefore have their own variables and values. The `mousePressed` method changes the value of `DrawingPanel.R` to 1 but not the value of `Baloon.R`.

Overriding the `mousePressed` method inside the `Baloon` class like suggested in the previous answer might solve your problem.

Comment: thank you, overriding the mousePressed method has solved the issue.

Comment: I have noticed now that for some reason, overriding is not working. Previously, I thought it was working because I had set the R variable equal to 1 in the constructor of DrawingPanel() class, which is why the console was printing 1 when I put the System.out.println(R) statement in the Balloon() class. Would you suggest any other solution?

Comment: I think i dont understand your problem. Does printing R from Baloon class now give you the value 0?

Comment: For some reason the value of R that is printing in the Balloon() class, is equal to the value of R that is set on the constructor of the DrawingPanel() class. However, any change in the value of R via the mousePressed() method in the DrawingPanel() class, does not show up in the print statement of the Balloon() class. To test out, whether the mousePressed() method affects the R value, I set R equal to 1 and created a print statement to print the value of R in the method. In the console, the value of R printed as 1. So the trouble is with Balloon() class not able to pick up the change.

Comment: Yes, that should be what i originally meant. Because of the inheritance, you have two seperate instances (one of DrawingPanel, one of Baloon). These two now have their own value and own variables. Changing one value of a variable does not affect the variable of the other instances variable.

Example: You initizalize R with 0. Then you instantiate both classes and now change the value of DrawingPanel.R to 1. Baloon.R still has the value 0, since they are two different variables.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Comment: I just posted my solution to the problem. Please take a look because I have another issue.

Comment: You set the value of rotate to 1 in the mousePressed() method of DrawingPanel, but never in the subclass. Maybe you should figure out a good point where you can set rotate value inside the subclass to 1. When mousePressed() of DrawingPanel is called, its value change has no effect on the subclasses rotate variable.

Comment: The change in value of the rotate variable after a mouse click, does have an effect on the rotate parameter of the subclasses. If you look at the paintComponent() method of the DrawingPanel() class, I pass on the rotate variable's value to the rotate parameter of the draw() method in the subclasses. I can't understand why the value that is being set for the parameter is always equal to the rotate value in the mousePressed() method of DrawingPanel() class after the click occurs.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didnt see that. Do you work with one or multiple instances of `DrawingPanel` ? If you do with just one, you never set the value of `rotate` back to 0. Once the value is changed from 0 to 1, it never changes back.

Answer (score 0):

Update # 1

I have figured out another method to get the rotate function of the program working.

**I changed the name of the variable `R` to `rotate`**

In the `DrawingPanel()` class, I have the following:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {
    private ArrayList<Balloon> balloons;
    private Balloon activeBalloon;
    private Color color;
    private DrawingPanel canvas;
    private boolean picked, stretching;
    private int offsetX, offsetY;
    private double offsetR;
    int rotate;

    // Constructor:
    public DrawingPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        balloons = new ArrayList<Balloon>();
        activeBalloon = null;
        picked = false;
        stretching = false;
        color = Color.BLUE;
        rotate = 0;
        System.out.println("This is" + rotate + "from the constructor of DrawingPanel()");
    }
 // Called from controlPanel when the "Add balloon" button is clicked.
// Places a new balloon with a random radius and the current color
// at the center of the drawing panel.
public void addBalloon(int shape) {
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    int radius = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * w / 2);
    switch (shape) {
    case 1:
        activeBalloon = new RoundBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
        break;
    case 2:
        activeBalloon = new OvalBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
        break;
    case 3:
        activeBalloon = new SquareBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
        break;
    case 4:
        activeBalloon = new FancyBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
        break;
    default:
        activeBalloon = new RoundBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
        break;
    }
    balloons.add(activeBalloon);
    repaint();
}
// Repaints this panel. If activeBalloon is set, paints it on top.
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (Balloon b : balloons) {
        if (!picked || b != activeBalloon)
        {
            System.out.println("This is rotate" + rotate + "from paintComponent()");
            //Added rotate parameter which takes the rotate value 
            //from mousePressed() method and passes to the draw()
            //object being drawn 
            b.draw(g, true, rotate);

        }

    }
    if (picked && activeBalloon != null)
        //Added rotate parameter which takes the rotate value 
        //from mousePressed() method and passes to the draw()
        //method for the balloon object being drawn 
        activeBalloon.draw(g, false, rotate);
}

// Called when the mouse is clicked on the drawing panel.
// If inside a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the offsets
// of the click from the center.
// If on the border of a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the
// distance of the click from the center.
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    rotate = 1;
    System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate + "from the mousePressed() method in DrawingPanel() class.");
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
    picked = false;
    for (int k = balloons.size() - 1; k >= 0 && !picked; k--) {
        Balloon b = balloons.get(k);
        if (b.isInside(x, y)) {
            picked = true;
            offsetX = x - b.getX();
            offsetY = y - b.getY();
            stretching = false;
            activeBalloon = b;

        } else if (b.isOnBorder(x, y)) {
            picked = true;
            offsetR = b.distance(x, y) - b.getRadius();
            stretching = true;
            activeBalloon = b;
        }
    }
    if (picked)
        repaint();

}
...
}
```

In the one of the subclasses of Balloon() class, SquareBalloon() I have the following:

```
public class SquareBalloon extends Balloon {
    public SquareBalloon() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a balloon with a given center, radius and color
     * 
     * @param x
     *            x-coordinate of the center
     * @param y
     *            y-coordinate of the center
     * @param r
     *            radius of the balloon
     * @param c
     *            color of the balloon
     */
    public SquareBalloon(int x, int y, int r, Color c) {
        super(x, y, r, c);
    }

    /**
     * Draws a solid circle if makeItFilled is true and outline only if
     * makeItFilled is false
     * 
     * @param g
     *            graphics context
     * @param makeItFilled
     *            draws a solid circle if true
     */
    public void draw(Graphics g, boolean makeItFilled, int rotate) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setColor(color);
        System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate + "from the draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
        if (makeItFilled) {
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, radius, radius);
            //Value from rotate parameter is used for the rotation
            if (rotate == 1) {
                System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate
                        + "from the makedItFilled if statement in draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
                g2d.rotate(90);
            }
            g2d.fill(rect2);

        } else {
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, radius, radius);
            //Value from rotate parameter is used for the rotation
            if (rotate == 1) {
                System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate
                        + "from the other if statement in draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
                g2d.rotate(90);
            }
            g2d.draw(rect2);

        }
    }
}
```

The rotation is fine. But the trouble now is that I can't figure out how to reset the value of the rotate parameter so that when I create a new object, the rotation does not occur.

In the current format of my code, the parameter only takes into account the value of variable `rotate` that is set on the `mousePressed()` method.

Can anyone suggest what I should do so that the rotate parameter takes into account changes to the value of the variable `rotate`, other than in the `mousePressed()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Update # 2

I fixed the issue, described on the previous post (Update #1).

The `DrawingPanel()` class looks like the following:

```
   public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {
    private ArrayList<Balloon> balloons;
    private Balloon activeBalloon;
    private Color color;
    private DrawingPanel canvas;
    private boolean picked, stretching;
    private int offsetX, offsetY;
    private double offsetR;
    int rotate;

    // Constructor:
    public DrawingPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        balloons = new ArrayList<Balloon>();
        activeBalloon = null;
        picked = false;
        stretching = false;
        color = Color.BLUE;
        rotate = 0;
        System.out.println("This is" + rotate + "from the constructor of DrawingPanel()");
    }

    // Called from controlPanel when the "Pick color" button is clicked.
    public void pickColor() {
        Color pickedColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(this, "Pick a color", color);
        if (pickedColor != null)
            color = pickedColor;
    }

    // Returns the current color.
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    // Called from controlPanel when the "Add balloon" button is clicked.
    // Places a new balloon with a random radius and the current color
    // at the center of the drawing panel.
    public void addBalloon(int shape) {
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        int radius = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * w / 2);
        switch (shape) {
        case 1:
            activeBalloon = new RoundBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
            break;
        case 2:
            activeBalloon = new OvalBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
            break;
        case 3:
            activeBalloon = new SquareBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
            break;
        case 4:
            activeBalloon = new FancyBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
            break;
        default:
            activeBalloon = new RoundBalloon(w / 2, h / 2, radius, color);
            break;
        }
        balloons.add(activeBalloon);
        repaint();
    }

    // Repaints this panel. If activeBalloon is set, paints it on top.
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Balloon b : balloons) {
            if (!picked || b != activeBalloon)
            {
                //Added this check to restore original angle of balloon 
                //objects. 
                if(rotate > 1)
                    rotate = 0;
                System.out.println("This is rotate" + rotate + "from paintComponent()");
                b.draw(g, true, rotate);

            }

        }
        if (picked && activeBalloon != null)
            activeBalloon.draw(g, false, rotate);
    }

    // Called when the mouse is clicked on the drawing panel.
    // If inside a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the offsets
    // of the click from the center.
    // If on the border of a balloon, makes it "active", remembers the
    // distance of the click from the center.
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //Value for parameter rotate is set here on mouse click
        //Changed the counter so its value is not set to 1
        //but it would add up. 
        rotate++;
        System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate + "from the mousePressed() method in DrawingPanel() class.");
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        picked = false;
        for (int k = balloons.size() - 1; k >= 0 && !picked; k--) {
            Balloon b = balloons.get(k);
            if (b.isInside(x, y)) {
                picked = true;
                offsetX = x - b.getX();
                offsetY = y - b.getY();
                stretching = false;
                activeBalloon = b;

            } else if (b.isOnBorder(x, y)) {
                picked = true;
                offsetR = b.distance(x, y) - b.getRadius();
                stretching = true;
                activeBalloon = b;
            }
        }
        if (picked)
            repaint();
    }
...
}
```

In the one of the subclasses of Balloon() class, SquareBalloon() I have the following:

```
 public class SquareBalloon extends Balloon implements MouseListener{
    public SquareBalloon() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a balloon with a given center, radius and color
     * 
     * @param x
     *            x-coordinate of the center
     * @param y
     *            y-coordinate of the center
     * @param r
     *            radius of the balloon
     * @param c
     *            color of the balloon
     */
    public SquareBalloon(int x, int y, int r, Color c) {
        super(x, y, r, c);
    }

    /**
     * Draws a solid circle if makeItFilled is true and outline only if
     * makeItFilled is false
     * 
     * @param g
     *            graphics context
     * @param makeItFilled
     *            draws a solid circle if true
     * @param rotate
     *            receives rotate variable value set in mousePressed() method of 
     *            DrawingPanel() class
     */
    public void draw(Graphics g, boolean makeItFilled, int rotate) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(color);
        System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate + "from the draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
        if (makeItFilled) {
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, radius, radius);
            if (rotate == 1) {
                System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate
                        + "from the makedItFilled if statement in draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
                g2d.rotate(45* (Math.PI/180));              
            }
            g2d.fill(rect2);

        } else {
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, radius, radius);
            if (rotate == 1) {
                System.out.println("This is the value of rotate" + rotate
                        + "from the other if statement in draw() method of SquareBalloon() class.");
                g2d.rotate(45 * (Math.PI/180));
            }
            g2d.draw(rect2);

        }
    }


}
```