# Java Swing: Making a growing circle by mouse click on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, graphics, mouselistener

I'm a beginner in Java and this time I'm trying to learn more by finding code examples and editing them, for example from this website. I have a JFrame and each time it (or more precise the JPanel in it) is clicked on, a circle is drawn which will grow/expand outwards like a water ripple. Each circle starts with a certain radius and will be removed or redrawn when reaching a bigger radius (I chose radius "r" from 10 to 200). I have two programs for this which almost work but are missing something. If I'm correct, I might also know what their problems are but I can't figure out how to solve them:

One generates growing circles but all of them have the same size, no matter when they're generated, since I can't find out how to assign the radius to a single circle. The code is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299786/draw-circle-on-jpanel-after-mouse-click/35300018):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Ripples extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    public int r = 10;
    private ArrayList<Point> p;
    
    public Ripples() {
        p = new ArrayList<>();
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                p.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        for (Point pt : p) {
            g2.drawOval(pt.x-r, pt.y-r, 2*r, 2*r);
        }
    }
    
        
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(r<200){
            r++;
        } else {
            r = 10;
        }
        repaint();
    }
    
    public static void Gui() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Ripples p = new Ripples();
        p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        f.setContentPane(p);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        Timer t = new Timer(20,p);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui();
    }

}
```

The other program(I've forgotten where I got it from) has circles with different radii depending on when they were generated, however the circles "flicker", because -as far as I understand- they are all processed at the same time, because the code doesn't include an Array to store and update each circle individually like the one above does:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Ripples extends JPanel { 
    int x,y;
    int r = 10;
    
    public Ripples(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y; 
        Timer t = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() { 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                if (r<200) { 
                    r++;
                } else {
                    r=10;
                }
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }); 
        t.start(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawOval(x-r,y-r,2*r,2*r);
    }
    
    public static void Gui() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Water Ripples");
        JPanel p0 = new JPanel();
        p0.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        f.add(p0);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setBounds(100,100,600,500);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
                Ripples rG = new Ripples(e.getX(), e.getY());
                rG.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                f.add(rG); 
            }
         });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui();
    }
    
}
```

So how can I solve this so that I get the circles growing independent from each other? I'd prefer a solution/improvement/hint for the upper code because I think its structured better than the second one. Also, I apologize for not splitting the code into more classes and for possibly not sticking to naming conventions. I appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Comment: For the first code, it looks like ``r`` is a constant, so the circles will be the same size. You'll need to change ``r`` depending on where your mouse it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I already tried to convert int r to int[] r and making for loops for the methods that use r. Also I tried not to use ArrayList<Point> but an arraylist that stores the values for x, y and r by making a new class, both approaches didn't work.

Comment: You should show us the code where you used an object that had a point and r as a new class. This sounds like a promising attack.

Comment: I've overwritten it but it was like this (class and implementation):
class Position {
    int x;
    int y;
    int r;
    public Position(int x, int y, int r){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }
}
\\In the Ripples class:
private ArrayList<Position> p;
\\In the mousePressed-Event of the Ripple-constructor:
p.add(new Position(e.getX(),e.getY(),r));

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't read code in the comments. Code is meant to be read formatted.

Comment: The second example flickers because there are multiple Ripples panels on top of each other.  I’m not sure how that is possible;  `f.add(rG)` should remove any prior panels from the BorderLayout of the JFrame’s content pane before adding the new one.

Comment: Since you're a beginner, you can't tell bad examples from good examples.  The [Oracle Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) is full of good examples.  Until you understand the principles behind Java Swing, you won't be able to create GUIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `Circle` class to your `Ripples` code.  This allows the `ActionListener` to treat each circle independently.

I started the GUI with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Ripples extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private List<Circle> circles;

    public Ripples() {
        circles = new ArrayList<>();
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                circles.add(new Circle(event.getPoint()));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
        
        for (Circle circle : circles) {
            Point p = circle.getCenter();
            int radius = circle.getRadius();
            g2.drawOval(p.x - radius, p.y - radius,
                    2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        for (Circle circle : circles) {
            circle.incrementRadius();
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public static void createGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Ripples");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Ripples p = new Ripples();
        p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        f.setContentPane(p);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);

        Timer t = new Timer(20, p);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Circle {

        private int radius;

        private final Point center;

        public Circle(Point center) {
            this.center = center;
            this.radius = 10;
        }

        public void incrementRadius() {
            radius += 1;
            radius = (radius > 200) ? 10 : radius;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public Point getCenter() {
            return center;
        }

    }

}
```

Edited to add:

I reworked the `Ripples` class code to separate the concerns.  I created a `DrawingPanel` class to hold the drawing panel, a `RipplesListener` class to hold the `MouseAdapter` code, an `Animation` class to hold the `Runnable` that runs the animation of the circles, a `RipplesModel` class to hold the `List` of `Circle` instances, and finally, the `Circle` class.

I could have used a Swing `Timer` for the animation, but I'm more familiar with creating and running my own animation thread.

Yes, this code is more complicated than the original example.  The coding style used here can be carried into larger, more complex Swing GUI development.

Here's the revised code.  I hope it's a better example.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Ripples implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Ripples());
    }

    private Animation animation;

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private RipplesModel model;

    public Ripples() {
        model = new RipplesModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ripples");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                stopAnimation();
                frame.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        animation = new Animation(this, model);
        new Thread(animation).start();
    }

    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }

    private void stopAnimation() {
        if (animation != null) {
            animation.setRunning(false);
        }
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private RipplesModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(RipplesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            addMouseListener(new RipplesListener(model));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));

            List<Circle> circles = model.getCircles();
            for (Circle circle : circles) {
                Point p = circle.getCenter();
                int radius = circle.getRadius();
                g2.setColor(circle.getColor());
                g2.drawOval(p.x - radius, p.y - radius,
                        2 * radius, 2 * radius);
            }
        }

    }

    public class RipplesListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private RipplesModel model;

        public RipplesListener(RipplesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            model.addCircle(new Circle(event.getPoint(),
                    createColor()));
        }

        private Color createColor() {
            Random random = new Random();
            int r = random.nextInt(255);
            int g = random.nextInt(255);
            int b = random.nextInt(255);
            return new Color(r, g, b);
        }
    }

    public class Animation implements Runnable {

        private volatile boolean running;

        private Ripples frame;

        private RipplesModel model;

        public Animation(Ripples frame, RipplesModel model) {
            this.frame = frame;
            this.model = model;
            this.running = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                sleep(20L);
                incrementRadius();
            }
        }

        private void incrementRadius() {
            List<Circle> circles = model.getCircles();
            for (Circle circle : circles) {
                circle.incrementRadius();
            }
            repaint();
        }

        private void sleep(long delay) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void repaint() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

    }

    public class RipplesModel {

        private List<Circle> circles;

        public RipplesModel() {
            this.circles = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void addCircle(Circle circle) {
            this.circles.add(circle);
        }

        public List<Circle> getCircles() {
            return circles;
        }

    }

    public class Circle {

        private int radius;

        private final Color color;

        private final Point center;

        public Circle(Point center, Color color) {
            this.center = center;
            this.color = color;
            this.radius = 10;
        }

        public void incrementRadius() {
            radius = (++radius > 200) ? 10 : radius;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public Point getCenter() {
            return center;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: First sentence from the OP. - *I'm a beginner in Java and this time I'm trying to learn more by finding code examples and editing them* - its hard to edit examples that do everything the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd prefer a solution/improvement/hint for the upper code

The second code is better because it uses:

1. a custom class to contain information about the object to be painted
2. an ArrayList to contain the objects to be painted
3. a Timer for the animation.

> because I think its structured better than the second one.

Not a good reason. Use the code that provides the functionality that you require.

Restructure the code yourself. That is part of the learning experience.

Issues with the second code:

1. It doesn't compile. Why post code that doesn't compile? This implies you haven't even tested it.
2. the initial radius is assigned when the `Position` object is created.
3. When the Timer fires you need to iterate through the ArrayList to update the radius of each `Position` object.
4. The radius of the `Position` object is used in the painting code.

As an added change, maybe call the `Position` class `Ripple`. Then you can add another custom property for the `Color` of the ripple. Then when you add the `Ripple` to the ArrayList you randomly generate a Color. Then in the painting method you use the Color property of the `Ripple` class. This is how you make objects and painting more flexible and dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I think my post wasn't structured well enough because I edited it too often - for a while I had three programms in it (the third one being a different version of the first) because I was asked in the comments to show another approach I tried (and knew it didn't work).

Comment: @user14240934, I thought you wanted to learn on your own and change the code on your own? How much to you learn if you just copy code without  know why the code is used? Yet you "accept" the answer that just spoon feeds the code with no explanation. How does this help in the future? The reason you had to ask the question in the first place was because you just copied code without truly understanding what it was doing..

Comment: Well, I accepted this answer because it highlights a solution, not only for me but also for anyone else that might be interested in it since there are many similar posts (like those I got the programs from).